# jquery validation rules for postal/zip code

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I got the following code which partially works. I need to validate Canadian postal if country is Canada `pay_id_1 == 1` or US zip code if `pay_id_1 == 234`.

```
var validator = $form.validate({
    ignore: ".ignore,:hidden:not(input[type='hidden'])",
    rules: {
        par_prenom_1: {
            required: true
        },
        par_nom_1: {
            required: true
        },
        par_adresse_1: {
            required: true
        },
        par_ville_1: {
            required: true
        },
        pro_id_1: {
            required: true
        },
        pay_id_1: {
            required: true
        },
        par_codepostal_1: {
            required: true,
            postalCodeCA: function() {
                if ($("#pay_id_1").val() === 1) {
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            },
            zipcodeUS: function() {
                if ($("#pay_id_1").val() === 234) {
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            }
        },
        par_telephone1_1: {
            required: true
        },
        par_courriel_1: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        par_naissance_1: {
            required: true,
            dateCA: true,
            daterange: ["1917-09-04", "2001-09-03"]
        },
        par_sexe_1: {
            required: true
        },
        que_2580_1: {
            required: true
        },
        que_2581_1: {
            required: true
        },
        que_2582_1: {
            required: true
        },
        que_2583_1: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        par_prenom_1: {
            required: "Veuillez entrer une valeur"
        },
        par_nom_1: {
            required: "Veuillez entrer une valeur"
        },
        par_adresse_1: {
            required: "Veuillez entrer une valeur"
        },
        par_ville_1: {
            required: "Veuillez entrer une valeur"
        },
        pro_id_1: {
            required: "Veuillez entrer une valeur"
        },
        pay_id_1: {
            required: "Veuillez entrer une valeur"
        },
        par_codepostal_1: {
            required: "Veuillez entrer le code postal/zip",
            postalCodeCA: "Veuillez entrer un code postal/zip valide"
        },
        par_telephone1_1: {
            required: "Veuillez entrer le numéro de téléphone",
            phoneUS: "Le numéro de téléphone doit être sous le format 555-555-5555"
        },
        par_courriel_1: {
            required: "Veuillez entrer le courriel",
            email: "Le courriel doit être une adresse valide"
        },
        par_naissance_1: {
            required: "Veuillez entrer la date de naissance",
            dateCA: "La date de naissance doit être sous le format AAAA-MM-JJ",
            daterange: "La date de naissance doit être entre {0} et {1}"
        },
        par_sexe_1: {
            required: "Veuillez entrer une valeur"
        },
        que_2580_1: {
            required: "Veuillez faire un choix"
        },
        que_2581_1: {
            required: "Veuillez entrer une valeur"
        },
        que_2582_1: {
            required: "Veuillez entrer une valeur"
        },
        que_2583_1: {
            required: "Veuillez entrer une valeur"
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is both rules apply for any country. Can you see what I can't?

Comment: Post the relevant HTML so a demo can be constructed.  While you're at it, strip out all irrelevant fields.  Just a minimal example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Also you are strictly checking equality between `$("#pay_id_1").val()`, which returns a string, and number literals, `1` and `234`. This will fail every time, even when `$("#pay_id_1").val()` is `'234'`. `'234' === 234 ==> false`. You have three options: 1) Convert `$("#pay_id_1").val()` to a number. Ex: `+$("#pay_id_1").val() === 1`. 2) Convert the numeric literals to string literals. Ex: `$("#pay_id_1").val() === '1'`. 3) Use the double-equals operator that runs automatic type coercion: Ex: `$("#pay_id_1").val() == 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to leverage the `.rules()` methods to dynamically change the rules on a field.

You can trigger the function using the `click` and `focus` events.  Use the `rules` object within the `.validate()` method to set any initial default rules.

Also, as stated in the other answer, you'll need to use quotation marks since the value from the field is a string.

```
$('[name="par_codepostal_1"]').on('click focus', function() {
    if ($("#pay_id_1").val() === '1') {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            postalCodeCA: true,
            zipcodeUS: false
        });
    } else if ($("#pay_id_1").val() === '234') {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            postalCodeCA: false,
            zipcodeUS: true
        });
    } else {
        // whatever
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/rb3fetuk/](https://jsfiddle.net/rb3fetuk/)**

Alternatively, you can trigger the rule change when you `blur` away from the `pay_id_1` field.

```
$('#pay_id_1').on('blur', function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '1') {
        $('[name="par_codepostal_1"]').rules('add', {
            postalCodeCA: true,
            zipcodeUS: false
        });
    } else if ($(this).val() === '234') {
        $('[name="par_codepostal_1"]').rules('add', {
            postalCodeCA: false,
            zipcodeUS: true
        });
    } else {
        // whatever
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/rb3fetuk/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/rb3fetuk/1/)**

Comment: The blur solution worked well.I added the change event.Thanks!